# opencv error on Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I tried the following code segment from [opencv example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html),

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('die.png')
dst = cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
```

But the I got the following error, what't he underlying reason and how to fix it?

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      4 img = cv.imread('die.png')
----> 5 dst = cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)
      6 plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
      7 plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst)

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.1) ..\modules\photo\src\denoising.cpp:178: error: (-5:Bad argument) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4! in function 'cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored'
```

Answer (score 2):

**cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored** is expecting a 8 bit image of 3 or 4 channels.
Try converting your image to uint8 before calling fastNlMeansDenoisingColored function

```
img=np.uint8(img)
```